# Does Apple Push APN provide a statistics API?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I didn't find this answer anywhere so decided to ask.

Does the Apple Push Notifications have a stats API or dashboard where we can see count for sent, received and opened?
Thanks.

Comment: There is no available dashboard from Apple, if you need statistics, you need to manually track them (via sending some info from your app to your backend) or you can use 3rd party service like Firebase Cloud Messaging.

Answer (score 0):

Apple does not provide that kind of dashboard. When you are calling the APNS server to send a push notification you receive a [response from the APNS server](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/handling_notification_responses_from_apns), that you can use to extract some statistics(mostly if the notification was send). If you need to know that the notification was opened you can manually track if the application was launched due to the user tapping the PN or an action of the PN.

Answer (score 0):

Now they have a console with metrics about pushes:
https://developer.apple.com/notifications/push-notifications-console/ .
You can see number of messages by push type, number of delivered and discarded messages for each type.